# Turn off AUTOCOMMIT in H2 Database Engine via SQL rather than via Java method

Tags: sql, h2, autocommit

How can I turn off AUTOCOMMIT in [H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) via SQL?

I want to start a transaction while using H2 from [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity). I understand that in JDBC we do not use `BEGIN TRANSACTION` calls in SQL. Instead we merely disable auto-commit.

So how to turn off auto-commit in a JDBC session with H2?

I see some `setAutoCommit( boolean )` methods on classes such as [`Session`](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/engine/Session.html#setAutoCommit-boolean-). Must I use one of those as a Java call?

Is there some SQL statement that I can use in my embedded SQL in my JDBC code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `SET AUTOCOMMIT OFF ;`

(as i see,) You have three options:

- via jdbc url, like: `jdbc:h2:./foo/bar;AUTOCOMMIT=OFF`
- via SQL statement: `SET AUTOCOMMIT OFF` (possible values: `TRUE | ON | FALSE | OFF`, *not supported in cluster mode*)
- via (`java.sql/`)`Connection.setAutoCommit(false)`

Refs:

- http://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#set_autocommit
- and http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html

Comment: Yes, `SET AUTOCOMMIT OFF` is what I need. I don’t know how I missed that in the documentation. I looked and looked, and searched.